# How to write conditional query in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5

How can I write this kind of queries in laravel 5.2 eloquent or query builder?

```
$query = Customers::leftjoin('Query string');    
if(condition)
    {
        //This part added to query   
    }
    else
    {
        //This part added to query
    }
->get();
```

Comment: Please read how to ask - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Its a good idea to have a tight title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remember your query in a variable, I.E. like this:

```
$query = Customers::leftjoin('Query string');   

if(condation){
    $query = $query->where('something', '=', 'something');
} else {
    $query = $query->where('somethingelse', '=', 'somethingelse');
}

$query = $query->get();
```

Normally you would have `$query->where()-get();`, which is basically the same thing, `$query` will hold the result of your `->where()` and allows you to chain further on `$query`